# Detect 7 segment fault on an LCD display

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, lcd

I have to develop an algorithm to detect faults on a LCD display with 7 segment characters. I started to develop the algorithm, but all I did til now was finding the Region of Interest (ROI), then display. This is how it looks:

[image]

There are 4 displays in the picture, and I find the regions where they are positioned. The display will be at the state with all the segments turned on, so it should be easy to detect any fault on them.

This is a raw image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0C0k.jpg)

This is a example of fault:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMNu4.jpg)

I just did the fault in the paint, but actually the faults would be basically a segment missing.

The result expected:

"The whole first 7 segment missing , and the third 7 segment the top segment missing"

Now I have to finally execute an algorithm to find faults on the segments, but I'm not sure how am I suppose to do it. I was thinking in using SVM and machine learning for detecting the characters, but I wonder if this is the best way of doing this, as I don't need an OCR for reading each character, I just have to know if all the segments are on or not.

How can I find faults on the segments?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps posting examples of the following would help: 1) Raw input image (i.e., image before thresholding). 2) Examples of a "fault" 3) Desired output.

Comment: If you want to use an SVM you'd need to gather more examples of faulty displays to use as a training set. However, I think a specialized solution that would normalize the LCD position and try to assess whether a segment is on or off could work better in this case

Comment: Hello Bartek, yeah, I totally agree.
I was thinking in having an image of the 7 segment which is working and make a feature comparison or template matching  and check if each 7 segment in the display is lighted properly .  I saw in my searches some solutions using feature detection, like at this example:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html

but as it is my first  image processing application , I don't really know which algorithm should I use to make this solution.